# Build survey app with Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I'm learning (and enjoying a lot) Ember.js. I'm trying to figure out the best way to create a survey: my idea is to use a different route for each of my question pages, so when you answer, you transition to the next route.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("question1", { path: "/q1" });
  this.route("question2", { path: "/q2" });
  this.route("question3", { path: "/q3" });
  this.route("questionN", { path: "/qN" });
});
```

Of course, any route has its controller and model. Problem is: when the survey reaches the last page and I must send data to the server, if the data is tied to the single route, how do I collect anything for sending? Is there any way to store the data outside the current route? How?

And: is there any way to prevent the user from entering /qN path if he has not answered all the previous questions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a model or a ember Object to storage all the data that you need and then submit that data to the server through Ajax.

Comment: Problem is any form is different: should I have one different model (or Object) for every page?

Comment: You can have the same model with differents properties.

Comment: I'm quite new to Ember and I don't know how to do this: can you point me to some good online resource?